# Highstock Column Chart dragging issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to display a stock chart with columns. But there is a strange issue I am facing right now. Even when the chart is completely zoomed out I am able to drag it.

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/j8cqzm4x/1/

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    alignTicks: false
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 1
  },
  title: {
    text: 'AAPL Stock Volume'
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
    data: [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
  }]
});
```

Can this behavior be avoided somehow? I have went through the documentation and none of the properties I have tried worked.

Note: In the same chart making the series as 'line' does not reproduce the same behaviour.

Comment: check this http://plnkr.co/edit/G0HTxTqvJeGDv0hirkQw?p=preview but it is different angular2 highcharts

Comment: I am facing the issues with column charts the code you linked seems to be for line chart. Any ways there was an issue in Highchart it seems. They have fixed it in the master branch should be available in the next release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Highcharts support for this. It seems there was an issue in highcharts which they have already fixed on the master branch. Using the updated code resolves the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/j8cqzm4x/4/

```
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

That is all that was needed, using master branch form github.